# Format line with code and comments in vim

Tags: vim

Using the following settings

```
set textwidth=40
set fo? -> formatoptions=croql)
set comments?    -> comments=sO:* -,mO:*  ,exO:*/,s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://
set cindent
set cinoptions   ->cinoptions=
```

If I enter insert mode and start typing the following line

```
    // abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
```

the line breaks at the 40th character, as expected:

```
    // abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
    // abc
```

Also, if a line longer than 40 characters is copied and pasted  as

```
    // abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
```

and command `gqq` is typed it ends up with the same result as above.

But I've noticed that if I enter insert mode and type the line below

```
    void funAbc(void) { // abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc
```

it doesn't break the line. If command `gqq` is entered it results in

```
    void funAbc(void) { // abc abc
        abc abc abc abc abc abc
```

I've expected that both inserting line longer than 40 characters or issuing `gqq` would break the comments and insert "//" in the next line - something similar to this:

```
    void funAbc(void) { // abc abc
        // abc abc abc abc abc abc
```

I've tried setting `'smartindent'` but it didn't solved the issue.

Is there any option/trick that can change the behavior of these comments starting after code?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is. The comment formatting with 'comments' and 'formatoptions' only recognises when the comment string is at start-of-line. The comment starting in the middle of the line is only recognised by the syntax-highlighter, not the formatter. For this reason I don't think it's possible in Vim as shipped. You might be able to find a plugin to do it, but a cursory search on the Vim website didn't turn up anything useful.