# Why does vim not recognize comments after non-whitespace characters? How can this be resolved?

Tags: vim

vim recognizes comments that start the line or follow only whitespace characters such as the ones below.

```
// This is recognized as a comment by vim.
// Pressing <Enter> continues the comment on the next line.
{
  // vim will also automatically format these comments if they exceed textwidth
  // characters in length.
}
```

However, when a comment follows code, vim does not seem to recognize it for the purpose of adding a comment leader in the following line.

```
DoSomething(); // vim does not recognize this as a comment
and will neither continue the comment after <Enter> is pressed nor break automatically if the line exceeds textwidth characters.
```

If it helps, my this is my ~.vimrc file. I usually `:set cindent`, but it seems to have no effect on comments.

```
set cino=L0,l1,g1,h1,N-s,t0,(0,w1,W2s
set expandtab
set formatoptions=croq
set shiftwidth=2
set tabstop=2
set textwidth=80
```

Thanks!

Comment: you must have a defective `cpp.vim` syntax file, I have no probs with comments of any type anywhere

Comment: @PaulEvans: I can easily reproduce this with vim 7.3 and no configuration files or modified cpp.vim file (same with `syntax=c` or `java`, or even `sh` using `#` comments...)

Comment: A similar question was asked 3 years ago, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666182/format-line-with-code-and-comments-in-vim/7668002#7668002.

Comment: As the similar question indicates, there are no formatoptions that addresses the scenario which has been identified.

Comment: I think it is exactly the same question that @Patrick referenced.

Answer (score 1):

Comments begining with `//` are valid ***to the end-of-the-line*** only.

Comment: Is there a way to get vim to continue c++-style comment blocks after the end of the line? On the topic of c-style comments, though, vim has issues even with those when they follow non-whitespace characters. Adding `set comments=sr:/*,mb:*,ex:*/` to my ~.vimrc works as expected when c-style comments start the line or follow only whitespace characters, but otherwise I have to add the "*" on the next line manually. Fortuantely, they do continue after that, but I'd like to make vim work with c++-style comment blocks. Thanks though.

Comment: get a more up-to-date version of `cpp.vim`

Comment: @PaulEvans: The same behavior can be seen in C, Java and even bash code (haven't tested more languages, but at this point I am not sure it is related to the syntax file as much as how the `r`, `o` and `c` options in `formatoptions` work). BTW, your answer is missing the point of the question